# Promoting of global symmetry to local one: what's the motivation?

Tags: symmetry, field-theory, gauge-theory

Consider a typical free Lagrange function $\mathcal{L}$ from quantum theory with *global* $U(1)$-symmetry ( e.g.  $ \mathcal{L}= (\partial_\mu \psi)(\partial^\mu \psi^*) + k^2|\psi|^2  $ ) with respect to the action

$\psi \rightarrow e^{-i\theta}\psi$

on matter field $\psi$ for constant $\theta$. Then we have a well known cooking recipe how to *"promote"* this global symmetry to a local one:

$\psi  \rightarrow e^{-i\theta(x)}\psi $

ie $\theta(x)$ is space dependent. The usual differential $\partial$ is going to be replaced by the covariant one $D:=\partial_\mu - iqA_\mu$ with respect the gauge bosons $ A_\mu$ ( morally the element from Lie algebra of $U(1)$) to  make the resulting Lagrangian invariant wrt now the local symmetry.

Naive question: What is this procedure good for, ie what is the advantage to turn global symmetry to a local one? Is there a deeper reason why local symmetry is more interesting for further consideration of the system?

Note that the question is not about *how* to perform this passing from global to local but really *why* it is important, so essentially  about the raison d'etre.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would argue the terminology "promoting a global symmetry to a local one" reflects the historical motivation, but not our modern understanding.

Historically (as far as I understand), Yang and Mills argued that because of locality and Lorentz invariance, no symmetry should truly be global, since an observer is only capable of transforming the fields locally. Following the chain of logic of a local symmetry leads you to introduce gauge fields associated with the local symmetry, that serve as connections in the gauge covariant derivative.

While Yang and Mills used this motivation that led them to make a fruitful discovery, in modern terms that is not how we think of things.

At least the way I think of it, the core physical principle is that we want to describe interacting spin-1 bosons. In order to make the interactions local, we make use of a gauge theory. The "making a global symmetry local" amounts to a formal trick that we know gives the right interactions for a gauge theory.

You can go a little deeper using the [iterative Noether procedure](https://arxiv.org/abs/gr-qc/0411023v3). We start with a free theory of spin-1 bosons, then try to add consistent interactions between the bosons and with charged matter fields. I won't go through the argument in detail here, but it turns out that to have consistent couplings the gauge fields must couple to a conserved current. To zeroth order in the gauge fields, the conserved current is guaranteed by the presence of a global symmetry and Noether's theorem. An iterative procedure can then be set up to calculate the consistent interactions, which amounts to determining how the conserved current should be modified to include dependence on the gauge field. This leads to Yang Mills theories.

Comment: in the second paragraph: what do you mean by the statement that an observer is only capable of transforming the field locally? Why is this a direct consequence of (of course resonable) assumptions that locality principle & Lorentz invariance should be satisfied by the theory?

Comment: Does it mean that if we require locality & Lorentz invariance, then for a (matter) field with dynamics described by a Lagrangian having a *global* symmetry the concept of observables would be not well defined? Or do I misunderstand this point?

Comment: @user267839 It's perfectly possible to have a local and Lorentz invariant theory with a global symmetry and well-defined observables. As I said, the historical motivation of Yang and Mills to consider local symmetries is no longer considered to be correct, even though the resulting Yang-Mills theory is correct. There's a lot of examples of wrong motivations leading to correct results in the history of QFT, like the Dirac's sea of negative energy fermions.

Comment: yes, but I would like  from didactical point of view firstly take a glace at the original motivation, before proceeding to the fact that it finally turned out to be wrong. Do you know the original source where the motivation is discussed? My concern is really just about the correct phrasing of the original motivation (which as you said turned out to be wrong). Could you check if I phrase the orginal motivation correctly?

Comment: So far I understand it, Yang and Mills originally seeked for a theory beeing 
**local** and **Lorentz invariant**. And they *conjectured* that such theory cannot have 
global symmetry if it should be compatible with phyical observations, that's what you mean in your answer?
My concern is just that I not understand your phrase that " an observer 
is only capable of transforming the fields locally" as statement. Could you formalize it? 
Does the statement as such says in physical terms that " any observable couldn't be invariant 
with respect to glocal symmetries, only the local ones"?

Comment: @user267839 The context of that quote is that historically, Yang and Mills believed symmetries should not be global. That's not how we think of things today. If a theory is invariant under a continuous global symmetry, then there will be various consequences covered in a QFT course: you'll be able to derive a Noether current associated with that symmetry, the correlation functions will transform linearly under the action of the global symmetry group, etc.

Comment: alright, I understand that the original motivation of Yang & Mills is no longer valid today. But what I still would like to understand is the precise meaning of following two phrases you used in your answer dealing with the historical part. Firstly, what precisely Yang and Mills understood by the term "*locality*" in this context? And secondly, what does the phrase that the "observer is only capable of transforming the fields locally" mean in more down to earth terms?

Comment: @user267839 A global symmetry requires transforming a field or set of fields $\phi_a(x)$ by some constant amount at every point in spacetime, for example in a shift symmetry we would shift $\phi(x) \rightarrow \phi(x) + c$ for a spacetime independent constant $c$. That requires transforming $\phi(x)$ at every spacetime point $x$. If you imagine that this transformation corresponds to an actual physical process, you need a huge army to shift the field at every point. Any individual observer can only interact with the field in a neighborhood around where they are located (that's locality).

Comment: My point is that you shouldn't think of a global symmetry transformation like $\phi(x) \rightarrow \phi(x) + c$ as an actual physical process, but a mathematical transformation. If that transformation leaves the underlying Lagrangian invariant, it implies the existence of some useful tools that can be used like a conserved Noether current.

Comment: let me try to rephrase how I understood you: you use the same notion $\phi(x) \rightarrow T(\phi(x))$ for the term "symmetry transformation", but the message is that one should keep in mind 
to carefully distinguish between two meanings of it: as an abstract transformation in pure mathematical sense, *not* coming from a physical process like interaction with an observer (these in case of beeing global provide exactly  conserved objects; so are in some sense "intrinsical" symmetries), *and* those which "happen" as physical processes, eg as an interaction with observer.

Comment: And then the original Yang & Mills philosophy tells that those of second type, the "physical" ones, can only be local, right? 
For example if a symmetry  transformation caused by an observer ( or any physically caused process) would be constant, eg  $\phi(x) \rightarrow \phi(x)+c$, then it would cause in spirit of this Yang Mills mantra an contradiction simply because it transforms at *any* point of spacetime as $\phi(x)+c$, so the effect is not local in sense above, simply since it acts nontrivially at *every* point in spacetime. That' s the logic behind it or do I missing the point?

Comment: If I understood your explanations so far correctly, could you check if following "consequence" is correct in sense of this Yang & Mills philosophy: say we have a state described by wave function $\phi$ and an observer stands at point $x_0$ and stays there. Then the observer interacts somehow physically with this state described by the wave function above. What can we say follwing the Yang Mills philosophy how this interaction (which should then "local") is described as transformation of $\phi$. Assume for simplicity the "form" of this trafo is $\psi(x)  \rightarrow e^{-i\theta(x)}\phi(x)$ with

Comment: space dependent $\theta(x)$. Can then the "locality" principle rephrased as that since the interaction is caused by observer standing at point $x_0$, only  $\theta(x) \neq 1$ with $x$ in neighborhood of $x_0$? Or does the "locality of interaction" does not mean this? (as before, the question is not if from "actual" research viewpoint this make sense, but from viewpoint of Yang Mills philosophy as a "thought experiment" *assuming* they were right)

Comment: a typo: it was meant $\theta(x) \neq 0 $ in last comment