# Original motivation for promoting global symmetries to local

Tags: symmetry, field-theory, gauge-theory, gauge-invariance, yang-mills

Assume we are dealing with a Lagrangian $\mathcal{L}$ for matter field $\psi$ which has a *global* $G$-symmetry and it's possible to promote this *global* $G$-symmetry to a local symmetry after the usual Yang Mills recipe to local symmetry, ie replacing the usual derivatives  by the covariant derivatives containing the gauge fields which garantee the local invariance.

> An classical example: Consider free Lagrange function $\mathcal{L}:= (\partial_\mu \psi)(\partial^\mu \psi^*) + k^2|\psi|^2 $  with global $U(1)$-symmetry
> $$\psi \rightarrow e^{-i\theta}\psi$$
> on matter field $\psi$ for constant $\theta$. Then we have a well known cooking recipe how to *"promote"* this global symmetry to a local one:
> $$\psi  \rightarrow e^{-i\theta(x)}\psi $$
> ie $\theta(x)$ is space dependent. The usual differential $\partial$ is going to be replaced by the covariant one $D:=\partial_\mu - iqA_\mu$ with respect the gauge bosons $ A_\mu$ making the resulting Lagrangian local gauge invariant.

Question: I'm looking for the original source where the historical motivation/background for posing this "promotion from global to local symmetry" is discussed. As @Andrew in his answer [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/770520/) explained, the original motivation turned out to be wrong, even if finally it initiated the construction of a correct theory.
And my concern is just where I can look up the discussion on this original motivation? (even if as Andrew said that it finally turned out to be wrong, I would like from didactical point of view take a closer look at it as a "start of my journey through this topic".)

So far I understood Andrew's historical short recap in the linked discussion correctly, Yang and Mills wanted originally to find a local and Lorentz invariant theory. And then they drawed a "conclusion", that this theory cannot have global symmetry, because "an observer is only capable of transforming the fields locally". But exactly this phrase I not understand literally.

What does it mean that "an observer is only capable of transforming the fields locally?" A guess: To turn it in formal physical language, does this phrase say that "any observable couldn't be invariant with respect to global symmetries, only the local ones"?